# What does "the case for" mean

Tags: meaning

Dr. Robert Zubrin, president of the Mars Society in the USA, has written several books on space science. One of these is entitled *The Case for Mars* on the exploration of this planet and soon another book will be published with the title *The Case for Space*.

What exactly does the phrase "The case for" mean?

Answer (score 1):

"Case" here means "arguments, facts, and reasons in support of or against something". The case for [exploring] Mars consists of arguments, facts, reasons, etc in support of that activity.

*die Argumente für/gegen* might be an equivalent in German, although that is off-topic.

[Case](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/case)